# LESS: Inheritance using a variable

Tags: css, less, font-awesome, web-essentials

I am learning to use a CSS preprocessor for the first time (LESS) and having trouble with trying to define a class which inherits a class when that parent class is a variable name..

This is basically what I want to do:

```
@import "font-awesome/font-awesome.less"

.icon-application-home{
    .fa .fa-home;
}
```

but as fa is defined in Font Awesome as this:

```
@fa-css-prefix:       fa;
```

then the less won't compile, because it doesn't recognize .fa. So I tried this instead:

```
@import "font-awesome/font-awesome.less"

.icon-application-home{
    .@{fa-css-prefix} .@{fa-css-prefix}-home;
}
```

However that is not working either. Is there any workaround? What can I do here?

**EDIT**

I found half an answer here:

[Missing Font-Awesome.less variables in my .less file after importing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20706688/missing-font-awesome-less-variables-in-my-less-file-after-importing?rq=1)

This works (partly) if I do the following:

```
@import (less) "../font-awesome.css";

.icon-home {
    .fa;
}
```

However, I noticed that `.fa-home` does not exist... only `.fa-home:before`... so I tried this:

```
@import (less) "../font-awesome.css";

.icon-home {
    .fa;
    .fa-home:before;
}
```

and

```
@import (less) "../font-awesome.css";

    .icon-home {
        .fa;
    }
    .icon-home:before {
        .fa-home:before;
    }
```

neither of these work. Any ideas?

Comment: I have to say Matt, your code works for me... perhaps a local problem?

Comment: @NicholasHazel: what are you using to compile the LESS? I am trying with Web Essentials 2012 for Visual Studio.

Comment: @NicholasHazel: ?!?! what kind of answer is that? How is it relevant to my question? All I asked you was what compiler you are using for LESS... Web essentials, SimpLESS or what?

Comment: My apologies. `I can't help you with your problem.` That would have been a better statement. *Deleting prior comment*. **I meant to say, don't use `visual studio`.**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming you use WE2012 that includes Less 1.4.2 the simplest solution would be:

```
@import (less) "../font-awesome.css";

.icon-application-home {
    &:extend(.fa, .fa-home all);
}
```

Or:

```
@import (less) "../font-awesome.css";

.icon-application-home
    :extend(.fa, .fa-home all) {

}
```

Read [`extend` documentation](http://lesscss.org/features/#extend-feature) for details on how this stuff works.

---

If you upgrade to an IDE/Compiler incorporating Less 1.6.x you will be able to do:

```
@import ".../font-awesome.less"

.icon-application-home {
    .fa;
    &:before {content: @fa-var-home}
}
```

There you still can't use `.fa-home` or `.fa-home:before` as mixins since the first is not defined and the second is not valid mixin selector, fortunately `&:before {content: @fa-var-home}` is just what `.fa-home` does.
In general though, the `extend` based solution is more optimal since it produces more compact CSS.

Comment: Thank you! By the way, is there any way to do the same thing just with the .less file I had? The one where the `.fa` was a variable (`@{fa-css-prefix}`)?

Comment: I've updated my answer with another method (provided that you'll need Less 1.6.x).